# sql query for recommender system : Inner join

Tags: database

I am trying to understand how recommendation systems use SQL, are they using self joins ? I have a table with the following important fields ,

```
orderID | productID
```

How can I query this table to say for any given product x , the top 5  products also bought with it were ...

Thanks in advance
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery selects all of the orderIDs that contain the productID that you are interested in.

You then select all of the productIds, and counts (joining with the product table to get the product name)

You group by the productID and name so that the count shows how many of each product are in total in the orders

```
SELECT o.productID, p.productName, COUNT(*) 
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN products p
ON o.productID = p.productID
WHERE o.orderID IN
(
 SELECT DISTINCT orderID 
 FROM orders
 WHERE productID = {insert productID here}
)
AND productID != {insert productID here}
GROUP BY o.productID, p.productName,
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thank  you, would you recommend another join to get the product name from the product table. ?

productID | procuctName

Comment: Yes exactly. Add an 
Inner join product p on o2.productID = p.productID 
Then add p.productName to the select.

Comment: My first half works very well, I cannot seem to get the second part right, where would you recommend I place the Inner join for the product name please ? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get error code 1064 in mysql workbench,I used
the code exactly as you provided it.

Comment: I just edited my response to include a different query that uses a subquery.

Comment: This works brilliantly, I guess there is no way to exclude our primary product that we are comparing against, as it always will appear in the subquery. We
could exclude it on the scripting side, but I cannot find a place to put the 
!= {product_id} part.